# Assigning every <td> to every cell in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the content from a table, which is within a `<div>` element, from a website. Currently, I can successfully login, navigate to the specific page and load the report, however, I am having difficulty pulling the data from that table.
I have looked up several sources, but sadly, haven't been able to implement this into the script.

This is what I currently have:

```vb
Option Explicit

Const MyUserID As String = "test123"
Const MyPassword As String = "test123"
Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4
Dim objIE As Object
Dim sPageHTML  As String

Public Sub LoginScript()

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .Silent = True
        .Navigate "https://www.mywebsite.com"
        Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        .Document.all.txtuserid.Value = MyUserID
        .Document.all.txtPassword.Value = MyPassword
        .Document.getElementsByName("btnSubmit")(0).Click
        Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        .Navigate "https://www.mywebsite.com/sample.html"
        Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .Document.getElementsByName("LocationID")(0).Value = "7"
        .Document.getElementsByName("endDay")(0).Value = "31"
        .Document.getElementsByName("endMonth")(0).Value = "12"
        .Document.getElementsByName("endYear")(0).Value = "2018"
        .Document.getElementsByName("view")(0).Click
        Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
        Range("A1:K500").ClearContents
        sPageHTML = .Document.getElementByID("printOut").innerText
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1") = sPageHTML
        .Navigate "https://www.mywebsite.com/logout"
        Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .Quit
        Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.Cpl, ClearMyTracksByProcess 11"
    End With

End Sub
```

I understand that the following line

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1") = sPageHTML
```

places the entire content into that single cell. Unfortunately, while trying out several options, I have had no luck trying to assign every TD to a cell.

The ID "printOut" is of the `<div>` element.

Below is the HTML content within the `<div>` element:

```html
<div id="printOut">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table><br>
    <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table align="center" bgcolor="#0080C0" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" bgcolor="#0080C0" class="white" nowrap width="150">
                                                    Ventura<br>
                                                    <a class="red" href="javascript:WinOpenPopup('s_ReservationBufferAdd.asp?dir=add1&amp;goto=Unallocating&amp;CarSizeID=&amp;PickupLocationID=')" title="Book"><img border="0" src="images/b_Unallocat.jpg"></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td class="texunderline"><b>Available</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td class="texunderline"><b>PickUp</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td class="texunderline"><b>Dropoff</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right" bgcolor="#0080C0" class="white" nowrap>
                                                    <a class="sheetwhite" href="javascript:WinOpenPopup('s_bookingListDaily.asp?date=2018-02-07&amp;LocationID=7&amp;CategoryID=3')" title="Wednesday"><small><font color="#E6E600"></font></small><br>
                                                    7 Feb&nbsp;</a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td align="right" bgcolor="#FF6262" class="white" width="50">0</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td align="right" class="texunderline" width="50">0</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td align="right" class="texunderline" width="50">0</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right" bgcolor="#0080C0" class="white" nowrap>
                                                    <a class="sheetwhite" href="javascript:WinOpenPopup('s_bookingListDaily.asp?date=2018-02-08&amp;LocationID=7&amp;CategoryID=3')" title="Thursday"><small><font color="#E6E600"></font></small><br>
                                                    8 Feb&nbsp;</a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td align="right" bgcolor="#FF6262" class="white" width="50">0</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td align="right" class="texunderline" width="50">0</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td align="right" class="texunderline" width="50">0</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table><br>
    <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table align="center" bgcolor="#0080C0" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" bgcolor="#0080C0" class="white" nowrap width="150">
                                                    Mavericks<br>
                                                    <a class="red" href="javascript:WinOpenPopup('s_ReservationBufferAdd.asp?dir=add1&amp;goto=Unallocating&amp;CarSizeID=&amp;PickupLocationID=')" title="Book"><img border="0" src="images/b_Unallocat.jpg"></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td class="texunderline"><b>Available</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td class="texunderline"><b>PickUp</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td class="texunderline"><b>Dropoff</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right" bgcolor="#0080C0" class="white" nowrap>
                                                    <a class="sheetwhite" href="javascript:WinOpenPopup('s_bookingListDaily.asp?date=2018-02-07&amp;LocationID=7&amp;CategoryID=2')" title="Wednesday"><small><font color="#E6E600"></font></small><br>
                                                    7 Feb&nbsp;</a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td align="right" class="texunderline" width="50">9</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td align="right" class="texunderline" width="50">0</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td align="right" class="texunderline" width="50">1</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right" bgcolor="#0080C0" class="white" nowrap>
                                                    <a class="sheetwhite" href="javascript:WinOpenPopup('s_bookingListDaily.asp?date=2018-02-08&amp;LocationID=7&amp;CategoryID=2')" title="Thursday"><small><font color="#E6E600"></font></small><br>
                                                    8 Feb&nbsp;</a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td align="right" class="texunderline" width="50">10</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td align="right" class="texunderline" width="50">0</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                                <td align="right" class="texunderline" width="50">2</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <form action="s_printToExcel.aspx" id="expExcel" method="post" name="expExcel" target="_blank">
                        <input id="htmlOut" name="htmlOut" type="hidden" value="">
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table align="center">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="notetext">Note:</td>
                <td class="notetext"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="notetext">1.</td>
                <td class="notetext">Today's Available = Yesterday's Available + Yesterday's dropoff (does not include same day drop offs) - Today's Pickup + NewFleetNo - OffFleetNo .</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="notetext">2.</td>
                <td align="left" class="notetext">The report includes unallocated bookings</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="notetext">3.</td>
                <td class="notetext">If you click on the date, you can see a listing of the pickups and drop offs for this day and location.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="notetext">4.</td>
                <td class="notetext">Please make sure all bookings have correct status, i.e., hired, returned, and cancelled if not hired. Incorrect status may cause incorrect vehicle current location.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table><br>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

I thought I'd share a "solution" to my issue, which partially works. Just not quite perfect.

```
Set elemCollection = objIE.document.getElementByID("printOut").getElementsByTagName("TABLE")

    For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)

        For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
            For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
            Next c
        Next r
    Next t
```

This extracts one of the tables within the `<div>` element, oddly enough not both, in case the reports provides two. The content, with multi-lines gets placed in a single cell row, which I then need to split, as seen below:

[image]

Here's a sample image of what the report looks like on the website.

[image]

Comment: There are nested tables in the sample, what is expected output on the worksheet?

Comment: @omegastripes I have uploaded an image of how it should look like in the worksheet. [link](https://imgur.com/28ktFON). I came across one way to handle this, but it's not ideal and only grabs the content from one table. The reports on the website sometimes displays two below each other, seen here [link](https://imgur.com/CuI5LcA)

Answer (score 0):

You should not work with the `div`, but with the `table`, and then loop for each `tr` and for each `td`. You can try something like:

```
    Dim table as HTMLTable : Set table = .document.getElementsByTagName("table")(Number of the table tag, counting from 0)

    dim i as integer: i = 1 'Starting from row 1
    dim j as integer: j = 1 'Starting from column 1 ("A")
    For each tr in table.Children(0).Children 'Children(0) of table is ussualy a tbody, use Children(1) if the table also contains a thead tag
        For each td in tr.children
            Cells(i,j) = td.innertext
            j=j+1
        next td
        i=i+1
    next tr
```

If you can't access the table by `id`, try accessing to it by `class` or by `tagName`, or by using `.Children(i)` on the `div` and subsequent children elements.

Edit: I edited the code so it should work without further editing, aside from the number of the table tag. Just paste this below `Range("A1:K500").ClearContents` and comment if it works. The number of the table tag should be the one you get by manually counting each `<table>` tag that appears in the HTML in order, starting from 0.

Edit2: Just saw the HTML. Instead of using `.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(Number of the table tag, counting from 0)` you can directly use `.document.getElementByID("printOut").children(0)` to initialize the `table` variable. The `.Children(i)` method returns the 'i'th children element of a tag, that is, the 'i'th tag nested in that specific tag. In this case, the div first (0) children would be the first table tag inside that div. If that is the table you are looking to get, leave it as `.Children(0)`. If not, try `.Children(1)` or `.Children(2)` for the other tables in the div.

Edit3: I just found I have some piece of code that does almost exactly what you want, except it copies the HTML table to a 2D array instead to the excel worksheet. You can then copy the array to the worksheet, or modify the code to copy the table directly to the worksheet.

```
Dim MatrizCO() as variant
ReDim MatrizCO(0 To 60, 0 To 1)
Dim table As HTMLTable: Set table = 
objIE.document.getElementById("DetalleContainerTbl")
On Error GoTo SalirFor:
For i = 0 To 60
    MatrizCO(i, 0) = table.Children(1).Children(i).Children(1).innerText
    MatrizCO(i, 1) = table.Children(1).Children(i).Children(8).innerText
Next
SalirFor:
```

Code explained: First, define the 2D array as a variant without dimensions and then `ReDim` it to have the dimensions (Rows,Columns) you need to copy the table (You can also hard-code the dimension on array definition but in my case I need the array to be dynamic). Then, you tell the program to exit the for loop on an error, in case the table dimension in each different case varies a bit. Then you loop through all rows i (and, in your case, you should also loop through all columns j). Finally you just asign every i,j position in the array to the i,j position in the table (Here, j's place would be where 1 and 8 are as arguments of .`Children`). Again, the first `.Children`'s of `table` argument is 1, because, in my case, the  has a  aside from the  tag. If there´s no , then the argument for it would be 0.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Nicholas! Unfortunately, the table has neither an ID nor a class assigned to it. I will try out what you suggested and will return with hopefully some good news.

Comment: @Francis - Can you include some sample HTML in your OP?

Comment: @BruceWayne I went ahead and added the HTML. Hope this helps

Comment: Sadly, so far no luck getting this to run. Getting a Type Mismatch error on `Cells(i, j) = td.innerText`.

Comment: I edited the code, try if it works now. The previous code was something like a pseudocode, but this one should work properly, aside from the number of the `<table>` tag.

Comment: @NicholasKemp Hey thanks! I tried it out again, but get the message that the variable `tr` isn't defined. Again, I am new to this, so I apologize for the question. Is this a matter of getting the correct reference ?

Comment: Mmm the `For each` loop should implicitly define the iterator, but you could always try explicitly defining it with `Dim tr as object` or  `Dim tr as HTMLTableRow`.

Comment: Check the edit, found a piece of code that uses a regular `For` loop instead of a `For each` loop

Comment: @NicholasKemp Thanks again for taking the time to go through this in detail. I went ahead and tried out the code, with some minor changes, and get a `Type Mismatch` error on this line `Dim table As HTMLTable: Set table = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("Table")`. Since the table doesn't have an ID associated with it, I assumed this would be the correct approach.